# SwiftUI Code throws error: No exact matches in call to instance method 'append'

Tags: ios, swift, post, swiftui, form-data

I wrote code to login user using form-data POST method where we login using email and password but it is showing me error: No exact matches in call to instance method 'append'

My code looks like this:

```
struct FirstSignIn: View {
    
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    @State private var driverID = ""
    @State private var pinTxt = ""
    
    @State private var edit1 = false
    @State private var edit2 = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            shortBgView()
            
            VStack {
                VStack {
                    Text("Welcome To CabsPoint")
                        .font(.custom(regFont, size: 28))
                        .foregroundColor(b80)
                        .padding(.bottom, 26)
                    
                    VStack {
                        ZStack {
                            TextField("Driver ID", text: $driverID) { edit in
                                if edit {
                                    edit1 = true
                                } else {
                                    edit1 = false
                                }
                            }
                            .frame(height: 16)
                            .padding([.leading, .vertical], 16)
                            .font(.custom(regFont, size: 12))
                            .tint(edit1 ? primaryColor : b80)
                            .foregroundColor(edit1 ? primaryColor : b80)
                            .border(edit1 ? primaryColor : b80, width: 1, cornerRadius: 6)
                            
                            ZStack {
                                Text("Driver ID")
                                    .padding(5)
                                    .font(.custom(regFont, size: 12))
                                    .tint(edit1 ? primaryColor : b80)
                                    .foregroundColor(edit1 ? primaryColor : b80)
                                    .background(.white)
                                    .offset(x: 15, y:-24)
                            }
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                        }
                        .padding(.bottom, 30)
                        
                        ZStack {
                            TextField("Pin", text: $pinTxt) { edit in
                                if edit {
                                    edit2 = true
                                } else {
                                    edit2 = false
                                }
                            }
                            .frame(height: 16)
                            .padding([.leading, .vertical], 16)
                            .font(.custom(regFont, size: 12))
                            .tint(edit2 ? primaryColor : b80)
                            .foregroundColor(edit2 ? primaryColor : b80)
                            .border(edit2 ? primaryColor : b80, width: 1, cornerRadius: 6)
                            
                            ZStack {
                                Text("Pin")
                                    .padding(5)
                                    .font(.custom(regFont, size: 12))
                                    .tint(edit2 ? primaryColor : b80)
                                    .foregroundColor(edit2 ? primaryColor : b80)
                                    .background(.white)
                                    .offset(x: 15, y:-24)
                            }
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                        }
                        
                        NavigationLink(destination: ForgotPasswordViews()) {
                            Text("Forgot Password?")
                                .font(.custom(medFont, size: 12))
                                .foregroundColor(b80)
                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .trailing)
                        }
                    }
                    .padding([.leading, .trailing], 32)
                    .padding(.bottom, 16)
                    
                    
                    
                    NavigationLink(destination: SecondSignIn()) {
                        Text("Log In")
                            .font(.custom(medFont, size: 14))
                            .foregroundColor(b80)
                            .padding([.leading, .trailing], 75)
                            .frame(height: 40)
                    }
                    .border(primaryColor, width: 1, cornerRadius: 100)
                }
            }
            .padding([.leading, .trailing], 20)
            .padding(.top, 25)
            
        }
        .adaptsToKeyboard()
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                NavBackButton(dismiss: self.dismiss)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func logInUser() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "muUrl.com") else {
            print("Invalid URL")
            return
        }
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        
        // set headers
        let boundary = "Boundary-\(UUID().uuidString)"
        request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        
        // create body
        let parameters = ["action": "driver_login", "email": driverID, "password": pinTxt]
        var body = Data()
        for (key, value) in parameters {
            body.append("--\(boundary)\r\n")
            body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n")
            body.append(Data(value.utf8))
            body.append("\r\n")
        }
        body.append("--\(boundary)--\r\n")
        request.httpBody = body
        
        // send request
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            // handle response
            if let data = data {
                if let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                    print("Response: \(responseString)")
                }
            } else if let error = error {
                print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

As I described, I wrote function for login:

```
    func logInUser() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "http://d.url.com") else {
            print("Invalid URL")
            return
        }
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        
        // set headers
        let boundary = "Boundary-\(UUID().uuidString)"
        request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        
        // create body
        let parameters = ["action": "driver_login", "email": driverID, "password": pinTxt]
        var body = Data()
        for (key, value) in parameters {
            body.append("--\(boundary)\r\n")
            body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n")
            body.append(Data(value.utf8))
            body.append("\r\n")
        }
        body.append("--\(boundary)--\r\n")
        request.httpBody = body
        
        // send request
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            // handle response
            if let data = data {
                if let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                    print("Response: \(responseString)")
                }
            } else if let error = error {
                print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }.resume()
    }
```

but it still shows error: No exact matches in call to instance method 'append' on line 17, 18, 20 and 22

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

The [`append`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/data/1779795-append) function of `Data` expects another instance of `Data`, but you are passing `String` instances.

In your case, you can use the [`utf8`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/utf8) string view to initialise a `Data` instance.  This won't work if correctly if your string contains sequences that cannot be represented in UTF-8.

You already do this when you add `value` to `body`. You just need to do it with the other strings.

For example:

```
body.append(Data("--\(boundary)\r\n".utf8))
```

You could also create an extension on Data:

```
extension Data {
   append(utf8String:String) {
        self.append(Data(utf8String.utf8))
   }
}
```

Then you can say `body.append(utf8String:"--\(boundary)\r\n")`